# how to find the preceding sibling of a link

Tags: xpath

I have the following I am trying to analyse using xpath

```
<table>
 <tr>

  <td>Name</td>
  <td>Info</td>
  <td><a href = "file1">Download</a></td>

</tr>

<tr>
 <td>Name2</td>
 <td>Info</td>
 <td><a href = "file2">Download</a></td>

</tr>

....

<tr>
..
</tr>

</table>
```

I have the following xpath to grab the download links

```
$xpath->query("//a[text()='Download']/@href");
```

What I am trying to figure out is the query to send to grab the Name of each of the downloads.

The page has no div id markups at all, just plain table, tr, td tags.

I have tried something like

```
$xpath->query("//preceding-sibling::a[text()='Download']");
```

Does anyone have any idea on this?

Answer (score 1):

Close!

Given a particular context node (here, the `href` attribute for a download), you want to find the eldest sibling of the `td` containing the context node.  So your relative path should first ascend to the `td` and then find the oldest sibling:

```
parent::a/parent::td/preceding-sibling::td[last()]
```

or more briefly (and without assuming that there are no elements like `p` or `span` intervening between the `td` and the `a`):

```
ancestor::td[1]/preceding-sibling::td[last()]
```

Some users find the reverse numbering of nodes on the `preceding-sibling` axis confusing, so it may feel simpler to say that what you really want is the first `td` child of the smallest containing `tr`:

```
ancestor::tr[1]/child::td[1]
```

If you need in a single pass to pick up all the download links *and* the textual label for them, then how you do it depends on the context in which you're using XPath.  In XSLT, for example, you might write:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="//a[text()='Download']/@href"/>
```

and then fetch the label in the appropriate template:

```
<xsl:template match="a/@href">
  <xsl:value-of select="string(ancestor::tr[1]/td[1])"/>
  : 
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

In other host languages, you will want to do something similar.  The key problem is that you have to iterate over the nodes matching your expression for `href`, and then for each of those nodes you need to move back in the document to pick up the label.  How you say "evaluate this second XPath expression based on the current node from the first XPath expression" will vary with your environment.

Comment: I'm writing this in PHP so the first $xpath->query("//a[text()='Download']/@href"); would give me an array of results. Then another xpath $xpath->query("NEW QUERY HERE"); would find me names of the links. I can then store them in a DB (name, download)

Comment: I'm still a little lost following your explanation above :(

Comment: Sorry.  What I'm driving at is that formally XPath expressions are always evaluated with a given *context node*.  For some expressions, the context node makes no difference; your first XPath expression is one of those.  But the expression `ancestor::tr[1]/td[1]` will find the label you want only if the XPath evaluation correctly takes the `href` attribute as the context node.  In the case of the PHP DOMXPATH::query method, you will need to specify the `href` attribute node as the second argument.   See [the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php).